# Visual Studio change in branches popup shows blank text

Tags: visual-studio

Has anyone encountered this bug in Visual Studio before? This occurs when I try to change branches with uncommitted changes:

[image: VS-Bug]

I've updated VS and have restarted my laptop as well. Been dealing with this for a week and no clue how to fix it.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Visual Studio IDE, submit a bug report.